# Safe to install this Xerox printer driver on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, drivers, printing

As the title says, is it safe for me to install this driver for a Xerox WorkCentre 7835 Printer on my Ubuntu 13.04 installation?

Because when I try to install them it says something about a bad package quality. I really don't want to break my Ubuntu setup.

[Here is the driver](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-7800-series/downloads/enus.html?associatedProduct=WorkCentre-78xx-built-in%20controller&operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en)

[Here is the log](http://pastebin.com/53hyuxYY)

Comment: give us the complete log information of the installation.

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/53hyuxYY

Comment: I'm also trying to get a xerox7835 installed properly on my laptop (ubuntu12.04 64bit) i have installed the ppd file and i was able to add the printer, the only thing that doesnt work is colour printing (other things like stapling works fine) For that reason i'm also tempted to install the deb that xerox provides, but i wonder if it will indeed solve the no-colour problem Ubuntu software center also tells me that it will be 75MB (!) once installed ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not sure where I found them on Xerox's site but I usually just download the .ppd file instead of the .deb package.  During the install of the printer when it asks for a driver or ppd file, i point it to that.

It looks like the main complaint about the deb is that the files should be owned by root instead of whoever it leaves it as.  That might be an easy post-install fix.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/view-and-extract-packages/ will tell you how to get the files out of a deb so you can examine them more closely in a safe directory.

The other errors:
E: XeroxPrtDrv: bad-package-name
E: XeroxPrtDrv: package-not-lowercase
E: XeroxPrtDrv: maintainer-address-missing Xerox

don't sound at all like a real problem.

The only one that does sound like a problem is:
E: XeroxPrtDrv: malformed-deb-archive found 4 members instead of 3
According to http://lintian.debian.org/tags/malformed-deb-archive.html
that is a serious problem.  I suspect the deb won't even work.  You probably need to contact Xerox and let them know they have a malformed-deb-archive problem with those packages.

Comment: I managed to find the PDD file, but when I try to print, it says a need a account password... I have no idea what to do now.

Comment: You probably have to provide an account code in order to print.  This code is usually used by your accounting department to keep track of printing costs. You most likely have to talk to them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to make xerox 7835 work with Ubuntu 13.10, and here are my current conclusions:

1. You can use the "install printer" wizard (via printer), and let the recommended choices (driver for 7345). With that you should be able to print
2. You can use the "xerox .deb", which will install your printer via the xeroxprtmgr (sudo). You may need to put printer IP if it's not found

The second solution is the only way to use "advanced features" such as "secure printing" or "stapler"...
In fact you have to run `sudo xerxprtmgr` and then configure an automatically found printer or add it manually (you need it's IP).
After that, a printing queue will be added, and you'll have a nice GUI configuration tool (like in windows) to configure your queue... Which will appear in the printer list.

The only problem, is that you have to configure a custom queue for each custom parameter assocations...
Don't hesitate if I can help more... I spent some time understanding the xerox driver concepts...

Answer (score -1):

Under **Ubuntu** you should follow the following rules:

### (1.) Try just connecting the printer.

Unlike Windows (XP, 7, 8, etc.), you do not normally need a driver. You may need a driver for some unusual function or lesser known brand/model, but most printers can just be plugged in.

### (2.) Look on the forums, for advice.

Some simple configuration may solve any minor issue, after step 1.

### (3.) Only use drivers from 'trusted' sources.

If you found the vendor / drivers site from a Google search (or equiv.), AND it does not warn you of malware (for that site), see what they recommend.

*Some random driver found on the Internet (often with an installer app.) can not always be trusted.*

Always read all install instructions carefully. Make sure they are for you version (release, 32bit or 64bit, etc.) of Linux.

---

### If you have tried all that, ask a question here ..

*Your original question would be best answered by trying it (the driver) for you, but we would also need the same model / brand printer for that.*